# How to made some function of component A running when close component B

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I try to used react-navigation! 
My app have two Component : A and B
From A i go component B, inside B i do some function and got value like isreload type boolean, i want to go back A and put it to A! Inside A if receiver value isreload, i do some function! Anyone can suggest me solution for handle this! Thanks guys so much!

here is my code at Component B, i don't know how to receiver reload at Component A and check if reload true: re-render component A, fail: stay

```js
    navigateToNewsFeed = (routeName, _reload) => {
        const backActionWithParams = NavigationActions.back({
            index: 0,
            actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({
                routeName,
                params: { isreload: _reload }
            })]
        });
        this.props.navigation.dispatch(backActionWithParams);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is related to event system in react native.

I suggest you refer to [DeviceEventEmitter](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.43/docs/native-modules-android.html#sending-events-to-javascript)

You could send message by `DeviceEventEmitter.emit('shouldUpdate', reRender);` in Component B , and register listener in Component A by

```
DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('shouldUpdate', (reRender) => {
        if(reRender){
           this.setState(...)
        } else {
           // stay
        }
    });
```

Remember to import DeviceEventEmitter